# How to populate a custom django admin change_form.html foreignkey field in select tag

Tags: python, django

I have arranged the templates of my project in the correct order so that I can inherit the django's admin change_form.html template for my model. Now I wish to customize the foreignkey field which is a SELECT dropdown. This is editable in case of superuser login and is just a select option for technical login. Based on selected value, wish to hide or display some of the other fields on the form. Can anyone give me a detailed example of how this can be achieved? I wish to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using jquery /javascript Solution is found at : [how to find the fieldset id in django's change_form.html using django jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968346/how-to-find-the-fieldset-id-in-djangos-change-form-html-using-django-jquery/8968377#8968377)