# how to find the fieldset id in django's change_form.html using django jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have many fieldsets in the change_form.html. Based on a click function I wish to hide/display some of the fieldsets. How do I get the fieldset id? There are more than 1 fieldsets.

In javascript 
eg.  $('fieldset')[1].hidden =true;  //false based on some condition

I want a django jQuery equivalent of the above statement.

I have tried, $("#fieldset")1 = true;
Also tried $("div.form-row.field1.field2").hidden = true;

I want to use django.jQuery only as below. How to access the fieldset 1, 2 and the show/hide functionality.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function($){
 //function to hide/show the fieldset related to POP3_status
 // if it is checked, show fieldset[1] and fieldset[2]
//if  it is not checked, hide fieldset[1], fieldset[2]

    $("#id_pop3_status").click(function(){
        var checked = $("#id_pop3_status").is(':checked');

        //not a POP3 account
        if (!checked){
        alert('not clicked');
                $("#fieldset")[1].hide();

        }
        //if the POP3_status is checked i.e it is POP3 account
        else {
        alert('clicked');
                $("#fieldset")[1].show();
        }
    });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("#fieldset").hide();
```

And if you later want to show it agian you can use

```
 $("#fieldset").show();
```

Comment: I added the class property and it works with the show/ hide functions

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the things you tried were valid jQuery:

```
$('fieldset')[1].hidden = true
```

1) When you subscript a jQuery object set, you get back a regular javascript object, so you actually need to do something like `$($('fieldset')[1])` to turn it back into a jQuery object. 2) `hidden` is not a valid property; you need either `.hide()`/`.show()` or something like `.css('display', 'none')`.

```
$("div.form-row.field1.field2").hidden = True
```

1) This will actually select `div`s that have the class "form-row" as well as "field1" **and** "field2", which won't match anything. What you're looking for is `$('div.form-row.field1, div.form-row.field2')`. 2) The same bit about `hidden` not being a valid property above applies

Comment: I used the $(".form-row.field1.field2").hide()  or show  i.e class and it works fine